# Disable data overlap in donut chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am working on a donut chart in Highcharts where I am displaying some data. The thing is that when the donut chart is displayed there is a little bit of overlap between the types of data. If you would like to see the chart in jsfiddle, here is the html for it

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

and the js code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
                startAngle: 90,
            innerSize: '99%',
            borderWidth: 16,
            slicedOffset: 40,
            borderColor: undefined,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    brightness: 1,
                    halo: {
                        size: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5,50]
    }]
});
```

If you hoover over one of the series in the donut chart, the line reaches into the other one. My question is that is there an option so the lines won't overlap each other, so the end is not rounded but have sharp edges that do not overlap? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to figure it out. All I had to do is to set the borderWidth to 0 and change the innerSize e.g 80% (this one depends on how wide you want the donut to be).

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

- you can use this custom code - but it works with the previous version of highcharts (8) - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/72015ojz/
- you can add some dummy points between the current one, set their `visibility` as false and set the `series.ignroeHiddenPoint` as false - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h2m0e35a/ - here you will need to implement some logic to calculate the amount and the values of those dummy points.